# How do I sum a column in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

I have a requirement that I need to sum a column in my SharePoint page then send a email if its one or bigger. I have got the email part down and its working, the problem is everything that I can fined only sums rows. Is there a way to do this with a calculated field, a workflow in SharePoint Designer, or a calculated column?

Comment: Very sadly... SharePoint cannot sum a column without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

In 2013 its best to apply CSR with a JSLink, but this method has some drawbacks like having to set the JSLink for every View, and not being able to (easily) have multiple Views on one page.

In SP2010 I used https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/Sum to Sum a Calculated Column (which can not be done with a View Total)

[image]

It uses Javascript in a Calculated Column to do the math while the page is loading.

http://https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/Sum shows how to built the Formula step by step. The complete Formula is:
(*remember to set the datatype to Number*)

```
="<div style=""color:"
 & IF(    [Rate]<[Buy]   ,"red","green")
 & """>"
 & DOLLAR(   [Qty]*[Rate]   )
 & "</div>"
 & "<div class=""vmSums"" style=""display:none;font-weight:bold;border-top:1px solid black;""></div>"
 & "<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
     & "var TBODY=this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode"
     & ",dataSum='data-vmSum',dataCnt='data-vmCount',total=value="
 &    [Qty]*[Rate]   
     & ",count=0;"
     & "if(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum)){"
         & "total=parseFloat(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum))+value;"
         & "count=~~TBODY.getAttribute(dataCnt)+1}"
     & "TBODY.setAttribute(dataSum,Number(Math.round(total+'e2')+'e-2').toFixed(2));"
     & "TBODY.setAttribute(dataCnt,count);"
     & "window.clearTimeout(window.vmSumFunc);"
     & "window.vmSumFunc=window.setTimeout((function(){"
         & "var lastrownr=~~TBODY.getAttribute(dataCnt),"
         & "last=document.getElementsByClassName('vmSums').item(lastrownr),"
         & "total=parseFloat(TBODY.getAttribute(dataSum)).toFixed(2);"
         & "last.textContent='$'+total;"
         & "last.style.display='block';"
     & "}), 100)"
 & "}"">"
```

Some things to note:

- Calculated Columns set to datatype:Number can output HTML (since SP2010)
- Using the SCRIPT tag was removed by Microsoft in summer 2013
- but loading a blank IMG can still trigger Javascript in the onload function
- This is all executed while the page is loading (so SP.js is not available and everything down the HTML page is not available yet)
- Javascript Timeout (canceled by every next IMG onload) trick is used to execute the final Display of the Total once.

#### CalcMaster Bookmarklet to edit Formulas

It is a PITA to debug Calculated Columns. Because you don't get feedback until you save a Formula and you end up having to click multiple times to get back to your Formula.

I have written a small 'CalcMaster' bookmarklet which hooks into the formula-editor and does a save of the Formula on every keypress; giving immediate feedback.
Recently published a first version on GitHub:

https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster